# Remove ilegal character string

Tags: android, character-encoding, bluetooth

I'm reading barcodes, qr, etc through a bluetooth device. I'm getting problems because I read QR codes with URL and I need to get some parameters of the url but invalid characters give me trouble.

Url : https��://portal.sidiv.registrocivil.cl/docstatus��?RUN=11111111-7��&type=��CEDULA&serial=107172548��&mrz=1071

This is how reading is because I'm doing in the method `'onKeyDown'`.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    char unicodeChar = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
    lecturaDoble+= unicodeChar;
    if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
        try {
            URI uri = new URI(url_rut_leida);
            QueryParamList params = new QueryParamList(URLEncodedUtils.parse(uri, "UTF-8"));
            rut = params.get("RUN");
            rut = rut.toUpperCase();
            rut = rut.replace("-", "");
            rut = rut.replace(".", "");
        }catch(URISyntaxException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to remove the invalid or characters well, cut the string to get just the RUN parameter which is what I need.

Comment: I assum u would like to rid of invalid characters. You can do this using, ie regexp. 
`urlWithInvalidChars.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}\\p{Punct}\\p{Digit}]+", "")`

Comment: Thank men !, I worked, now I still do not get what I want because the URL remove the = which basically is for the parameters, but do another code to identify when the word is RUN and see how I can cut it. @zepar

Comment: I've looked at your code once again, and i have one question, how do you get `url_rut_leida` string?
As I see, `char unicodeChar = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();` you casts several bytes unicode char to one byte char, maybe it causes a problem?